# How to get file extension (compare)

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, compare

i´m parsing the filedirectory from dropbox into a mutablearray, to show it in a table view.

how can i compare the file extension? (.doc, or .jpg,....)

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:@"??????"] ) {

    [cell.extensionView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"word.png"]];
}
```

isEqualToWhat? is it possible to use wildcards?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the question.  `NSString` has a `pathExtension` method if that's what you're trying to compare.

Comment: pathExtension perfect! thx word

Comment: So Phillip should make his response an answer then @HugoBoss approve it so you both get points. (I cannot get the @ tag for Phillip to take)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `stringWithFormat` unless you actually have a format. Your code would be much cleaner if you did something like this:

```
NSString *filename = [text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *ext = [filename pathExtension];
if ([ext isEqualToString:@"doc"]) {
    [cell.extensionView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"word.png"]];
} else if ([ext isEqualToString:@".jpg"]) {
    [cell.extensionView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jpeg.png"]];
}
```

There is a better way than setting up this big `if-else` block. I imagine you have lots of different extensions you wish to check. Setup a dictionary with the extensions and images. Something like:

```
NSDictionary *extensionThumbnails = @{
    @"doc" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"word.png"],
    @"xls" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"excel.png"],
    @"jpg" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"jpeg.png"]
};
```

Add an entry for each extension and image you have. Then your original code (now using modern Objective-C syntax) becomes:

```
NSString *filename = text[indexPath.row];
NSString *ext = [filename pathExtension];
UIImage *thumbnail = extensionThumbnails[ext];
if (!thumbnail) {
    thumbnail = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.png"];
}
[cell.extensionView setImage:thumbnail];
```